# How do I create a multiline string in Raku?

Tags: string, raku, multiline, template-literals

In JavaScript (ES6), you can use template literals (``) to create multiline strings as shown in the following example:

```js
const html = `
  <div>
    <p>Raku is <b>ofun</b>.</p>
  </div>
`
```

What's the Raku equivalent of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my constant html = '
  <div>
    <p>Raku is <b>ofun</b>.</p>
  </div>
';
```

works fine in Raku.

However, you probably want to use a so-called [heredoc](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/heredocs%20%3Ato):

```
my constant html = q:to/HTML/;
  <div>
    <p>Raku is <b>ofun</b>.</p>
  </div>
HTML
```

omits the first newline but is otherwise the exact equivalent. If you want to interpolate variables, you can change `q` to `qq`:

```
my $lang = <Raku Rust Ruby>.pick;
my $html = qq:to/HTML/;
  <div>
    <p>$lang is <b>ofun</b>.</p>
  </div>
HTML
```

For way more than you probably want to know about quoting, see [Quoting Constructs](https://docs.raku.org/language/quoting)

Comment: Also, if you don't want the final newline, you can do `qq:to/HTML/.chomp`.  Technically, you could also do `.chop`, but I find `.chomp` to be mnemonically better is it indicates a newline being removed.